# Suppress python markdown wrapping text in <p></p>

Tags: python, markdown, jinja2, templating

I'm using python [markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/) as a filter for Jinja2 to generate html. As part of that, I fill in table entries from the render input. Passing the input through the markdown filter always wraps the text in paragraph tags, and thus every entry in the table is wrapped in `<p></p>`, which I don't want.

I've read through the markdown docs and the 3rd party extension lists, but it appears there's no way to suppress this behavior other than writing my own extension. Is there no other way to suppress the paragraph tag wrapping? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

**Update**: Here's the filthy dirty awful hack I'm using for now:

```
def safe_markdown(text):
  p = '<p>'
  np = '</p>'
  md = markdown.markdown(text)
  if md.startswith(p) and md.endswith(np): #you filthy bastard
    md = md[len(p):-len(np)]
  return jinja2.Markup(md)

env = jinja2.Environment(...)
env.filters['markdown'] = safe_markdown
```

**Update 2** (Response to Aaron's answer):

Appreciate the help, but it's definitely the markdown causing the problem. Here's an example portion of the jinja template:

```
        {%- if spc.docs -%}
<td>{{ spc.docs|markdown }}</td></tr>
        {%- else -%}
<td></td></tr>
        {%- endif -%}
```

If `spc.docs` is simply `'foo'` the generated html will wind up as `<td><p>foo</p></td></tr>` unless I use the filthy hack.

**Update 3**

Here's a less nasty hack, although still a hack and not really an 'answer', IMO.

```
def safe_markdown(text):
    md = markdown.markdown(text)
    return jinja2.Markup(md)

def safe_markdown_td(text):
    text = ''.join(['<td>', text, '</td>'])
    return safe_markdown(text)

env = jinja2.Environment(...)
env.filters['markdown'] = safe_markdown
env.filters['markdowntd'] = safe_markdown_td
```

Then the template becomes:

```
        {%- if spc.docs -%}
{{ spc.docs|markdowntd }}</tr>
        {%- else -%}
<td></td></tr>
        {%- endif -%}
```

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer. It's also a dirty hack, but maybe not a dirty *filthy* hack. It feels better than a `startswith` and `endswith` call, though.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you use markdown, you have to accept some pretty severe compromises on the final structure of the html. There are a host of structures you simply cannot express. Don't think of it as a substitute for html, think of it as another language to simply write content.

What might be happening is that wrapping your table cell contents in paragraph tags is messing up your layout, in which case you should fix that with CSS:

```
td p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just stumbling on this same issue - unwanted start/end paragraph tags free-of-charge from `markdown.markdown()`.

The following works well for me, for strings that I do not want `markdown()` to wrap as paragraphs. Rather than calling `markdown()` directly, I wrap the call in a regex that strips out the offending paragraph marks, and in a way that does not interfere with any [intended hard-wraps](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p) embedded in my markdown.

```
from markdown import markdown

# ... other stuff ...

def no_p_markdown(non_p_string) -> str:
    ''' Strip enclosing paragraph marks, <p> ... </p>, 
        which markdown() forces, and which interfere with some jinja2 layout
    '''
    return re.sub("(^<P>|</P>$)", "", markdown(non_p_string), flags=re.IGNORECASE)

# ... other stuff ...

non_p_html = no_p_markdown("my markdown text not intended for a paragraph")
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree, that hack is filthy (but better than nothing).

In my experience weirdness inside tables, and specifically `<td>`, was due to malformed markup. This may be the same issue in your case.

```
>>> import markdown
>>> markdown.version
'2.1.1'
>>> text = '''
... <table>
... <tr>
...     <td>
...             Here's some fancy text
...
...             and some more
...     </td>
...     <td>Here's other text</td>
... </tr>
... </table>
... 
... This should be in a **paragraph.**
... '''
>>> markdown.markdown(text)
u"<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        Here's some fancy text

        and some more
    </td>
    <td>Here's other text</td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>This should be in a <strong>paragraph.</strong></p>"
```

^ See? No crazy paragraph tags in the table.

There's also the remote possibility that Jinja is drunk, and adding these tags. I haven't noticed that behavior personally, but it may be worth trying this experiment with and without the template filter.

One more thing. Markdown rocks, and while you will be loosing *some* control, I think you've made an excellent choice.

**Edit** Sorry Elhefe, I wasn't exactly understanding what was happening. I've had this problem, too! My solution: wrap that junk in `<div>` if I don't want paragraphs.

```
>>> markdown.markdown(text)
u'<p>Here be some <em>foo</em></p>'
>>> text = '<div>Here be some *foo*</div>'
>>> markdown.markdown(text)
u'<div>Here be some *foo*</div>'
```

But this doesn't solve your problem. The only thing I can think of is either wrapping the text in `<td></td>` prior to marking-down.

Comment: WAT? This is strange indeed. Two secs while I give it a shot -- nevermind, I wasn't understanding what was happening! Comment on OQ.

Comment: Re Edit: You're then mixing the model and the view, and may God have mercy on your heathen soul. I will pray for you.

Comment: Actually, nm - there is a way of making that work without disturbing the model. See OQ.

Answer (score 1):

... yet another way to remove the irritating outer tags is to write a simple stripping function:

```
def strip(s):
    """ strips outer html tags """

    start = s.find('>')+1
    end = len(s)-s[::-1].find('<')-1

    return s[start:end]
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when I was using Markdown to add HTML markup to some user defined strings in a config file so that they didn't have to learn HTML (that's what Markdown is for, right?). Those strings get embedded in other HTML which may already be a

element. So I didn't want another one in the middle. Two things:

1. Markdown's convert() does not add

   tags to the supplied text if it is already wrapped with any block-level tag (listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements).
2. If that doesn't work for you then I extended Markdown to override the convert() method to strip

   tags.

```
    from markdown import Markdown
    class EMarkdown(Markdown):
    def convert(self, text):
        t = super().convert(text)
        t = t.removeprefix("<p>").removesuffix("</p>")
        return t
```

Extending this to all block-level tags is left as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with `<p> </p>` tags messing up my tables. The easiest solution for me was to fix this in css by adding

```
td p {display:inline;}
```